# Using mercurial to manage linux kernel, tags, and hg id

Tags: mercurial, linux-kernel

Anybody using mercurial to manage a linux kernel?  This is a bit long, but I'm not sure if there's an answer to this.  I wanted to give some examples for help

Here's what I'm seeing:

Within the linux kernel, there's a command used when building called scripts/setlocalversion.  Inside this script, it sets the kernel version based on the repository information.  Currently, it understands git, mercurial, and svn repo's.

For git, it creates the tag with this code:

```
if head=`git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD 2>/dev/null`; then

    # If we are at a tagged commit (like "v2.6.30-rc6"), we ignore it,
    # because this version is defined in the top level Makefile.
    if [ -z "`git describe --exact-match 2>/dev/null`" ]; then

        # If we are past a tagged commit (like "v2.6.30-rc5-302-g72357d5"),
        # we pretty print it.
        if atag="`git describe 2>/dev/null`"; then
            echo "$atag" | awk -F- '{printf("-%05d-%s", $(NF-1),$(NF))}'
.....
```

So, here's an example I did to understand how this works:

```
[1536][mcrowe:test]$ git tag -a -m"Creating a tag" KernelTest
[1537][mcrowe:test]$ git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD 
d024e76
[1537][mcrowe:test]$ git describe --exact-match
KernelTest
[1537][mcrowe:test]$ git describe
KernelTest
```

So, in this example, the local version would be set to "KernelTest" when the kernel builds.

In mercurial, however, the code to get the local version is this:

```
if hgid=`hg id 2>/dev/null`; then
    tag=`printf '%s' "$hgid" | cut -d' ' -f2`

    # Do we have an untagged version?
    if [ -z "$tag" -o "$tag" = tip ]; then
        id=`printf '%s' "$hgid" | sed 's/[+ ].*//'`
        printf '%s%s' -hg "$id"
    fi
....
```

My expectation was that I could tag a release, and have that tag be what this script uses, as happens in git.  However, it appears that "hg id" never prints out the tag like this script expects:

```
[1546][mcrowe:test2]$ hg tag -m"Creating a tag" KernelTest -r tip
[1548][mcrowe:test2]$ hg id
3ccda5e738ae+ tip
[1548][mcrowe:test2]$ hg tags
tip                              115:3ccda5e738ae
KernelTest                       114:be25df80ce76
```

So that act of tagging changes the revision so hg id will never show what the tag is.

***Core Question***:  AFAIK, this would never work for the linux kernel.  The question is how should this be implemented in the kernel tree to allow `hg tag` to perform like `git tag`?

Comment: tag adds an extra commit by default, maybe try localtags instead ? `tag -l`

Comment: Wish I could, but this is getting pushed into a continuous integration server.  Need global tags, unfortunately.

Comment: Tags as commits is a feature not a bug. :)  See my answer below for something that might work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing:

```
hg log -r . --template '{latesttag}'
```

I think that does what you want.

There's also `{latesttagdistance}` which can let you know you're N commits past a tag for handy version string.

Comment: Perfect.  I'll post the final code shortly incorporating this

Comment: Note that if a revision has two tags, they will both be returned with a colon separating them ("tag1:tag2")